# Fitting in a Succah precedence - kids, parents, women or guests

Tags: halacha, sukkah, priorities, hachnasat-orchim-guests

When there's no place for everyone in the Succah, who takes the precedence:

1. one's sons (underage and grown-ups)
2. one's parents/grandparents
3. women (wife, grown-up daughters)
4. the guests (male/female)?

Please specify about sitting the first night, following days, and sleeping in the succah.

---

This looks simple, but, in fact, it is a very complicated question as it compares seemingly unrelated Mitzvot - Succah, Chinuch, Honoring Parents and Hospitality. Each one of them is well known, but when they come together ... I couldn't figure out how do I even start to weight them.

1. The homeowner is out of the question and even compared to his father, he takes precedence (B"M).
2. What rights do his wife and the grown-up kids and the guests have on his Succah? Is he lending it - is it a property? Can the homeowner expel the kids just because it is his property, and then let in whoever he wants?
3. תשבו כעין תדורו - does the precedence of his own house apply - like he his father would take precedence around his Shabbos table over his sons I suppose. But in this case, his wife would be the first, for she does have some obligation so she can even say the blessing.
4. If one invites a [male] guest, does it automatically imply that he shares his Succah?

*Let's limit it to the Litvakes communities.*

Comment: Why invite guests if you don't have room?

Comment: @DoubleAA Shuccos happens, somebody's gotta leave.

Comment: Don’t forget that the women aren’t actually obligated in Sukkah, so they would take last precedence when compared to the men who actually are obligated. The children have a mitzvah of chinuch, which means they at least have a mitzvah d’Rabbanan, which is more than the women have.

Comment: @DonielF To tell the truth, the question was inspired by a story about R' Diskin of Kohl Torah's Yeshivah here in Jerusalem, whose wife refused to leave Succah when guests arrived claiming that after all Rabeynu Tam, by allowing to sey the blessing agreed that there's ome sort of obligation still.

Comment: @AlBerko What was the psak? To me that sounds like a terrible reading of that Rabbeinu Tam on her part.

Comment: @DonielF All I heard was the fight, they (women) refused to leave. Maybe we can infer that he did ask them to? I just wanted to say that some women (and Rabbis) might think that women's obligation after permitted to say Brocho is very serious.

Comment: @AlBerko Yes, but Rabbeinu Tam provides the reasoning that they’re allowed to make the bracha - since they’re permitted to do Mitzvos Asei Shehazeman Gerama, even if they’re not obligated to do so, they can say “He Who commanded us.” With that logic in hand, do you not see how her argument falls apart? Perhaps Shalom Bayis could potentially be a factor, but I can’t believe that this Rabbeinu Tam alone is justification to give the women as much if not greater priority over those who are actually commanded to sit in the Sukkah.

Comment: @DonielF Maybe she held "תשבו כעין תדורו" - if so, the Succah is the extension of her house? Maybe she held that the guests would be מצטער פטור? After all, it's not their private Succah?

Comment: @DonielF Another point - If one is obligated to support his wife (also in Mitzvot) is one obligated to provide her a Succah (for Ashkenazi)?

Comment: @AlBerko I dunno, maybe. I doubt this comment section is the place to discuss this, though.

Answer (score 2):

[Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 640:1-2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.640.1?lang=bi):

> נשים ועבדים וקטנים פטורים מן הסוכה...‏
>
> קטן שאינו צריך לאמו שהוא כבן חמש כבן שש חייב בסוכה מדברי סופרים כדי לחנכו במצות:‏
>
> Women, slaves and minors are exempt from the *sukkah*...
>
> A minor who does not need his mother, i.e. around age five or six, is obligated in the *sukkah* rabbinically, in order to educate him in *mitzvot*.

So the order of precedence would be:

1. All adult males (over 13) - obligated biblically
2. All male children older than five / six - obligated rabinically
3. Everyone else (females, male children younger than five/six) - exempt

The obligation to eat and sleep in the *sukkah* would seem to be equivalent (see [Shulchan Aruch 639:1-2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.639.1?lang=bi)).

If they all have the same level of obligation, they all need to eat in the sukkah. If they can't all fit, I guess they need to eat in shifts...

Comment: +1 but the interesting part is between father, grandfather, sons > 13, guests, etc. I have been wondering since reading the question ...

Comment: @mbloch Is there any reason to think that there should be a distinction between these people? If they all have the same level of obligation, they all need to eat in the sukkah. If they can't all fit, I guess they need to eat in shifts...

Comment: Agree. So who goes first? Is there a specific order? I would guess father first, then maybe grandfather, then maybe guests (because of the mitzvot of *kibud va'em* and *hakhnassat orkhim*)

Comment: I'm not convinced this answer is right.  The grandmother for instance might become before her grandchildren because of תשבו כעין תדורו.  If I had a choice between my grandmother eating with my grandfather in the house and me eating outside, or me eating with my grandfather in the house and my grandmother outside, I would 1000% pick the former.

Comment: @Heshy I understand the logic of what you’re proposing, but it would be a huge chiddush. I would be very surprised if you can find a source that paskens that way.

Comment: @Heshy JoelK it's not really more of a Chiddush than the Rama about sleeping inside with your wife. Not that that's very convincing either, but there are real people who practice it.

Comment: 1. Thank for the answer. 2. I don't see the connection between the citation into your conclusion, how does it follow from it? 3. I edited the question and added some interesting points. It seems that you only addressed the question of Succah, overlooking other considerations.

Comment: Is this assuming a jointly owned sukkah by all? Otherwise the owners of the sukkah would seemingly get precedence independent of gender and age.