# Is a man obligated to provide a Succah for his grown-up sons?

Tags: halacha, sukkah

I started with the ["succah-precedence"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95136/fitting-in-a-succah-precedence-kids-parents-women-or-guests) question but it turned out some other premises are unclear.

1. One is obligated to provide shelter for his kids (let's say up to 18-22 Rambam Ishut 12:14)
   .
2. One is obligated to provide a Succah for his underaged kids as a Mitzvah of Chinuch (to make them used to stay in Succah. Mishnah Succah).

**Is a man obligated to provide a Succah for his grown-up sons**
(13-22 that live with him, of course)?

*(Let's imagine one flies abroad and leaves his sons at home)*

Comment: Do you have a source for your first assertion?

Comment: @JoelK I thought it is pretty much a consensus (deRabanan), isn't it? if not, bring it down to 13-15, that's not the point. OK?

Comment: I don’t know what the consensus is. That’s why I asked. Maybe there’s no responsibility to provide shelter after age 13?

Comment: @JoelK As far as I know it is Tnay Ketuba, and some say Tzdekah and some say Gma"CH but all agree one has to provide the living for his kids at least until they start working on their own.

Comment: @AlBerko Still not providing a source, and “until they start working on their own” is much more vague than “let’s say up to 18-22.” A better wording for your point seems to be “One is obligated to provide shelter for his kids who are still living at home” with a source provided. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Why would providing a Succah be any different than providing other items for an adult child (whatever that obligation may be)? If one is obligated to provide something for a child, that presumably means it has to be provided in a halachically correct manner (i.e. if you have to clothe your child, you probably don't fulfill that obligation by providing Shatnez).

Comment: @DonielF Added sources

Comment: @Salmononius2 Good point, finally someone tries to help. If so, that would be a financial obligation, like buy them a Lulav, to cover the Mitzvah's expenses. But does he have to bother?

Comment: @AlBerko That Rambam says nothing to the effect of what you claim he says. “Just as a man is obligated to feed his wife, so is he obligated to feed his young (״הקטנים״) sons and daughters up to six years old. From then on he feeds them until they grow up (״עד שיגדילו״), as per the decree of the Sages.” So you misquote him on several counts: he only discusses food, not all necessities, and he says until they are גדולים, not until they move out. Further, he says that we don’t force him after they turn six. (Con’t)

Comment: (Con’t) I’d also like to add that Shulchan Aruch YD 251:3 holds that if one feeds his children over Bar/Bas Mitzvah it’s considered Tzedakah - not a special chiyuv to feed them. He brings down this Rambam in Even HaEzer 71:1, so it’s not like the Mechaber argues on the Rambam.

Comment: @DonielF Can we get back to my question please - what does it support?

Comment: @AlBerko I didn’t realize we had left your question. I’m challenging your assertion in point #1, in that the Rambam you cite has absolutely nothing to do with the claim you make. I further supported my argument by quoting the Shulchan Aruch’s position on the matter and demonstrating that he agrees with the Rambam. Therefore, you’re left with a question based on an unsubstantiated claim.

Comment: @DonielF Can I just wipe out the premises and leave the question? I just gave some background information, nothing more. If you know an answer - let's discuss the obligation, but #1 is a different question. And I am sure it is covered somewhere on this site.

Comment: @AlBerko I think this is a fine question without the premises; I see no reason to argue against that.

Comment: I don't understand the question -- after the age of 13 they have an onligation to eat/sit/sleep (whatever) in a sukkah. It could be their father's or their school's or their own. Are you asking whether he can kick them out if they eat in his?

Answer (score -2):

Yes; if he can and they need it. See Shulchan Aruch YD 251:3 & 4.

If one's sons aren't financially stable, and he is; he is obligated to support his children until they are because of the mitzvah of tzedaka and kerovim(see Rama ibid.). If he is unable to support himself, and relies on others; then he is exempt and his children are obligated to support him(if they are able; Rama ibid).

This rule is true to the extent that beit din can obligate him to do so, if his sons have no other way of attaining their financial needs and the father is able to support them(ibid.).

Comment: Please provide a full answer, and bring the source.

Comment: And how those Hilchot Tzedakkah connected to Succah?

Comment: Did you see it inside? He writes it explicitly "in order to teach them the straight path".

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35154)

Comment: @DannySchoemann The mitzva of tzedaka obligates a man to provide for his children *if he can* even after the age of six. The halacha sourced above answers it. So, yes; he *is* obligated because of the mitzvah of tzedaka and beit din can *force* him to do so if need be.  Although he doesn't have to buy them one if they live with him; they can use his(even without his permission and be yotze!).

Comment: it says: הַנּוֹתֵן לְבָנָיו וּבְנוֹתָיו הַגְדוֹלִים, שֶׁאֵינוֹ חַיָּב בִּמְזוֹנוֹתֵיהֶם, כְּדֵי לְלַמֵּד אֶת הַבָּנִים תּוֹרָה וּלְהַנְהִיג הַבָּנוֹת בְּדֶרֶךְ יְשָׁרָה, וְכֵן הַנּוֹתֵן מַתָּנוֹת  לְאָבִיו וְהֵם צְרִיכִים לָהֶם, הֲרֵי זֶה בִּכְלַל צְדָקָה. וְלֹא עוֹד אֶלָא שֶׁצָּרִיךְ לְהַקְדִּימוֹ לַאֲחֵרִים - you have to feed and teach them - but where does it say you have to provide them with all their Mitzva needs? they are adults who have to do their own Mitzvot.

Comment: @DannySchoemann It doesn't. But why teach them Torah if they're just going to go to clubs and chase girls? It should be clear that it also means providing them with the means to do obligatory mitzvot so that they stay on the derech(and it's the same with anyone asking for tzedaka).